# Editing Wordpress Template

Tags: javascript, java, php, wordpress

I have a site for which I use Wordpress. We have a debate group in our class. So the template I use has a feature so that non-members can also post comments with email and name.

I wanted to change that setting but am unable to do it.

Kindly suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only registered and logged in user can comment. It's inside Settings->Discussion there is a checkbox as shown in screenshot. Put a check mark in the box and click Save Changes at the bottom of page. Done.[image: Screenshot of Discussion settings]